# Java Heap Space in Weblogic 12.1.3 Deployment

Tags: java, spring, deployment, weblogic

When i start my Weblogic 12 and deploy my app for first time everything runs good, but when I undeploy the app and deploy again it gives me a java heap space when the app works with streams at one point, but first time it is deployed it runs good. If I want to restart my app, I need to restart weblogic to have no error.

I don't know why first time everything is ok, and later when restart only the app, it gives me that error...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have some memory leaks.

I advice you to start jvisualvm (comes with jdk) and monitor and profile the memory for the java process started by weblogic.

Another option is to generate a heapdump and analize it with a tool like MAT 
http://www.eclipse.org/mat/